# Find the shortest unique sublist

Tags: code-golf, array

Given a list of lists find the shortest list that is a contiguous sublist of exactly one list.

For example if we had

```
[[1,2,3],
 [1,2,3,4],
 [2,4,5,6],
 [1,2,4,5,6]]
```

the shortest contiguous sublist would be `[3,4]` since it only appears in the second list.

If there is no unique contiguous sublist (this requires at least one duplicate entry), output an empty list.  Here is an example

```
[[1,2,3],
 [1,2,3],
 [1,2]]
```

If there are multiple contiguous sublists of minimal size, you may output any one of them or a list containing all of them.  For example if the input was

```
[[1,2,3],[2],[1],[3]]
```

You could output either `[1,2]`, `[2,3]` or `[[1,2],[2,3]]`.  If you choose to do the latter option you may output singleton lists for the cases where there is only one solution.

The output may occur in the *same* list more than once as long as it appears in no other list.  For example

```
[[1,2,1,2],[2,1]]
```

should output `[1,2]` because `[1,2]` is a sublist of the first list but not the second, even though it is a sublist of the first list in two different ways.

You may take as input a list of lists containing any type so long as that type has more than 100 possible values, i.e. no Booleans.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so answers will be scored in bytes with less bytes being better.

### Test Cases

```
[[1,1]] : [1]
[[1],[1]] : []
[[1,1],[1]] : [1,1]
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>12</s> <s>14</s> 15 bytes

+3 bytes for case `[[1,1]]`

```
Ṡḟȯ¬€Ṡ-uÖLṁȯtuQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@HOBQ93zD@x/tCaR01rgBzd0sPTfB7ubDyxvqQ08P///9HRhjqGsbEA)

#### Explaination

```
          ṁ      -- map and concatenate
           ȯt    --   all but the first
             u   --   unique elements of
              Q  --   contiguous sublist
        ÖL       -- sort by length
Ṡḟ               -- find the first element satisfying this predicate
  ȯ¬€            --   not an element of
     Ṡ-          --   the list of sublists minus
       u         --   its unique elements
```

Note: `Ṡ f g x = f (g x) x` and this is hard to explain using the method above.

Comment: [14 bytes](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@GO@ed2n9uqnPCoac2jxg2HdmoenubzcGdjIJDz////6GhDHQMdII7ViTYAswyBLEMwHQsA) with a lambda.

Comment: That [fails](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@GO@ed2n9uqnPCoac2jxg2HdmoenubzcGdjIJDz////6GhDHcPYWAA) for `[[1,1]]`

Comment: Hmm, and fixing that makes it over 15 bytes. Oh well.

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, 15 bytes

```
halDs-M.p.:R)QY
```

[Test suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=halDs-M.p.%3AR%29QY&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D%2C+%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%5D%2C+%5B2%2C4%2C5%2C6%5D%2C+%5B1%2C2%2C4%2C5%2C6%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D%2C+%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D%2C+%5B1%2C2%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D%2C+%5B1%2C2%5D%2C+%5B1%2C2%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D%2C+%5B1%2C2%5D%2C+%5B2%2C3%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D%2C+%5B1%2C2%5D%2C+%5B1%2C3%5D%2C+%5B2%2C3%5D%5D&debug=0)

First, we generate all substrings of each input list with `.:R)Q`. Then, we generate all possible orderings, of those substring groups `.p`.

Now for the tricky part: `-M`. This folds the `-` function over each ordering list. It starts with the first substring list, then filters out all occupants of all of the other lists.

Then, the results are concatenated, ordered by length, a `[]` is appended, and then the first element of the resulting list is extracted with `h`.

This would be 4 bytes shorter if I could error on no unique sublists rather than output an empty list.

Comment: What is your 11-byte version?

Comment: @LeakyNun `hlDs-M.p.:R` is probably what he means.

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth - 20 bytes

```
Ksm.:d)QhalDfq1/KTKY
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Ksm.%3Ad%29QhalDfq1%2FKTKY&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D%2C%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%5D%2C%5B2%2C4%2C5%2C6%5D%2C%5B1%2C2%2C4%2C5%2C6%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D%2C%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D%2C%5B1%2C2%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D%2C%5B2%5D%2C%5B1%5D%2C%5B3%5D%5D&debug=0).

Comment: Got [16 bytes](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=hfq1%2F%60sQtP%60Tsm.%3A&input=%5B%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D%2C%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%5D%2C%5B2%2C4%2C5%2C6%5D%2C%5B1%2C2%2C4%2C5%2C6%5D%5D&debug=0), but I'm not sure this is correct. Otherwise it's pretty similar.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman cool, you should post it.

Comment: Fails for the recently added edge case test `[[1,1]]`.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, 251 + 19 = 270 bytes

A very gross lambda from, minimally, `List<List>` to `List` (best to cast it to `Function<List<List<Integer>>, List<Integer>>` though). It's a brute force solution that iterates chunk lengths from 1 to the size of the largest list, in each case iterating over every chunk of that length in every list and checking each such chunk against each chunk of equal size in every other list.

Fear me, garbage collector.

```java
import java.util.*;
```

```java
i->{int x,l=x=0,s,t;for(List z:i)x=Math.max(x,z.size());List r=i;while(l++<=x)for(List a:i)c:for(s=0;s<=a.size()-l;s++){for(List b:i)for(t=0;t<=b.size()-l;)if(b.subList(t,l+t++).equals(r=a.subList(s,s+l))&a!=b)continue c;return r;}return new Stack();}
```

### Ungolfed lambda

```java
i -> {
    int
        x,
        l = x = 0,
        s, t
    ;
    for (List z : i)
        x = Math.max(x, z.size());
    List r = i;
    while (l++ <= x)
        for (List a : i)
            c: for (s = 0; s <= a.size() - l; s++) {
                for (List b : i)
                    for (t = 0; t <= b.size() - l; )
                        if (b.subList(t, l + t++).equals(r = a.subList(s, s + l)) & a != b)
                            continue c;
                return r;
            }
    return new Stack();
}
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##dVHBjtsgFDzbX0EvFdQEbdvdHkKIVFWqVKl7snpa7QE7JEsWgxees04sf3uKHTdpVtoLYt7MPB5vtnInZ65Wdrt6Puqqdh7QNtZYA9qwTzxN66YwukSlkSGge6kt6tKk9nonQaEAEiJ5cawbW4J2lv2cLovfOsDp@GVBbZRfLim6xmit7SqvpDEqwB@rXxqVD68GQOKoZ8tOW0AtNaIVNzRQ4Gvn8dACHeaatOJewhOrZItbemBBHxQmhI@8F5q/PmmjsMmyhWjJ2Smjs5wPMIgbHhZCTs6Z4SHLSHdWFlE5AIg6WIjioiN6jSNsikGHgZoMopOpl0aagP3QcuICDZkh5KP8IApSOgvaNgqV3CtovEWe99PNqleUgyyfMeH9MYn7T6YAplXvnF6hKsaAc/Dabh4ekfSbQIZUknwfQFXMNcBiQhaMxbGavLteJuva7EdNcsnwu/dyH1gAr2SFh4mmpB4e42vdqE66zxR9oehrT68xRbfnUsS3FN1R9O2N6rrakxMZI6zx2zHmcxmGFf7TlC5@o4T/dKc52Y8T4Xxg4Malk9EzHISnSZ/2x78)

## Java 8, 289 + 45 = 334 bytes

This is a more functional approach using streams. If there were a method on `Stream` to reduce to only elements that appear once, this solution would have beaten the one above. Assign to the same type as above.

```java
import java.util.*;import java.util.stream.*;
```

```java
l->{List<List>o=l.stream().flatMap(a->IntStream.range(1,a.size()+1).boxed().flatMap(n->IntStream.range(0,a.size()-n+1).mapToObj(k->a.subList(k,k+n)))).collect(Collectors.toList());o.sort((a,b)->a.size()-b.size());for(List a:o)if(o.indexOf(a)==o.lastIndexOf(a))return a;return new Stack();}
```

### Ungolfed lambda

```java
l -> {
    List<List> o = l.stream()
        .flatMap(a -> IntStream.range(1, a.size() + 1)
            .boxed()
            .flatMap(n -> IntStream.range(0, a.size() - n + 1)
                .mapToObj(k -> a.subList(k, k + n))
            )
        )
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
    ;
    o.sort((a, b) -> a.size() - b.size());
    for (List a : o)
        if (o.indexOf(a) == o.lastIndexOf(a))
            return a;
    return new Stack();
}
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##dZLBbtswDIbP9lPoKLWysHTdDvFiYBgwoECLHrydih5oRw4U25In0WmzwM@eSbGTLs3mg0yR/Eman9ewgcR0Uq@X9V61nbFI1t4nelSNuErjC59DK6ENobjri0aVpGzAOfIASpNdHHVWbQAlcQjog2/CqtclKqPF98n4cq8cjsedRrmSNss4Ob@TSull3kLTSIc/tfrVyzx0dUgW@ybJdqcamVkch6NMVA3gA3QUkszXyseZLeiVpDMOwqnfkrLrGROFeZXLvwT6UvDhJEh0kLTQ/TCPxZrWSeYjfRHa05rX15r5R5TGT1si/Ta@jXUCzSGHsdQI5/dJKfCCHeRj4WIyWFoZS0MygblhqqJG@A3I18eKAlssjPDLxruTh1mJvdUE0snQ8oXkCGVNWTrsI08pmjBNQDZGLUnrYVH/kUqvnp4J2JVjgV2Ubx3KVpgeheeosdHUe6P/QhDQdc32kBO9kf5qLWzdEUaYaOL59Oy77Q7Z0W7GyQ0nHwd@fufk9uTy91tOPnHy@V3WuXdgYzCQoe/HmM/BhX0ec450Lv7of@EKmnCwNI6GeNj/AQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>149</s> <s>128</s> <s>126</s> 113 bytes

```hs
import Data.List
f l=[x|x<-l,sum[1|y<-l,y==x]<2]
h[]=[]
h(x:y)=x
i=h.f.sortOn length.(>>=tail.nub.(>>=tails).inits)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7NCsIwEITP5in22MIaaP05SOPJo@IDhBwiVruYxGIipOC719iigh6Wmfl2WabR/lIb0/dk2@stwEYHzbfkAzuBETI@YjU16O9WFo/uZTshoqpKxRqphEySxVWXi8hINPzEfXqyd2Bqdw4Nz9ZrETQZ7u6HT/A5J0fB530dtW1N7UGAZBMpCyxxpnBUnCdX4hwXuFQIAxyDwr/jUX825YummX148XbD5kuHpBhjVpNLbY5XYBOr2x1k7Y1c4JTDu2z/BA)

*Saved 21 bytes thanks to Wheat Wizard, H.PWiz and Bruce Forte.*

*Saved two more bytes thanks to H.PWiz.*

*Saved 13 bytes thanks to nimi.*

**EDIT** This was the original explanation:

> - `a` is a shortcut for joining lists.
> - `s` computes all the continous sublists (all `tails` from all `inits`). Note that `nub` keeps only the first occurence of each element, so `tail` will remove the empty list from the sublists.
> - `g` merges all sublists from all given lists in a big list of sublists, and sort them by length.
> - `f` f is a filter on elements that appear only once in the big list
> - `h` is a secure version of `head`
> - `i` is the glue
>
> Quite inelegant! There should be a better solution...

Comment: It looks like a couple of your functions could be shorter if written as point-free functions.

Comment: You also don't have to count the `i=` at the end of your program because point-free functions do not need to be assigned according to our rules.

Comment: Is `foldl1(++)` just `concat`?

Comment: `(length$filter(==x)l)` could be shorter as `length(filter(==x)l)` or even shorter as `sum[1|y<-l,y==x]`

Comment: @H.PWiz Except for `[]` it is, but `>>=id` is even shorter ;) Also @jferard: You can inline a lot of functions (eg. `f`,`g` etc.) since you only use them once.

Comment: @H.PWiz thanks, but I don't understand your last comment. The result is `[3,4]`, as expected. Or do I miss something ?

Comment: @jferard No, I just edited your code without realising that I introduced a bug, sorry

Comment: @H.PWiz No problem. And thanks for the brackets!

Comment: Each time your are using `concat`, it's followed by `map` (or `<$>`), so you can use `concatMap` or `>>=` from the list monad instead and drop the definition of `a`: `i=h.f.sortOn length.(>>=tail.nub.(>>=tails).inits)`.

Comment: @nimi thanks. I just started to study monads.

Comment: @jferard: the great thing about monads is that you don't have to study them if you want to use them. Whenever you have a `map` and a `concat`, you can use either `concatMap`or `>>=` (or it's alter ego `=<<`). `>>=`/`=<<` just happen to be the "bind" operation from the list monad. Nevertheless it's useful to understand monads.

Comment: You can use `sortOn(0<$)` instead of `sortOn length`, see [this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19255/tips-for-golfing-in-haskell/146634#146634).

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 bytes

```
Ẇ€Q€ẎɓċỊµÐf⁸LÐṂ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hrrZHTWsCgfjhrr6Tk490P9zddWjr4Qlpjxp3@Bye8HBn0////6OjDXWMYnVApI4hkAaSQDoWAA)

-3 bytes thanks to Jonathan Allan

Comment: Can `ċ1` be replaced with `S`?

Comment: @ThePirateBay Indeed it can, thanks. I made a different version though. (though it would bring it to the same bytecount)

Comment: Your new solution prints `[1, 2, 1]` for input `[[1,2],[1,2,1],[2,1,1]]` while `[1,1]` is shorter.

Comment: @ThePirateBay Fixed, thanks.

Comment: `Ẇ€ẎµċÐ€=1Tị⁸LÐṂ` should avoid the register for a byte I think...

Comment: @WheatWizard Nah, that's just because Jelly's representation of an empty list is nothing: [see a Python representation here](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hrrZHTWse7uo7tPJI9@EJQPahdbaGIQ93dx9a53N4wsOdTf8Ptx@d9HDnjP//o6MNdYx0DGN1oHQsAA)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Ok thanks!  I thought it might be the case but I wanted to let the people who actually know Jelly look at it.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Ah nice. Thanks.

Comment: Another two like so: `Ẇ€ẎɓċỊµÐf⁸LÐṂ`

Comment: @JonathanAllan Thanks!

Comment: ruh-roh, all the methods fail edge case just added to tests: `[[1,1]]` (since `[1]` is a substring of `[1,1]` twice). EDIT: I think `Ẇ€Q€ẎɓċỊµÐf⁸LÐṂ` would fix that for two.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Oh rip :( well thanks for the fix :D

Comment: @JonathanAllan oh um. I can't count whoops. :P

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 15 bytes

```
εŒÙ}€`{γʒg}€`éн
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//3Najkw7PrH3UtCah@tzmU5PSwczDKy/s/f8/OtpQR8FIRwFExuooRIOYsbEA)

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 14 bytes

```
sfq1lT.gksm{.:
```

[Try it here.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=sfq1lT.gksm%7B.%3A&input=%5B%5B1%2C+2%2C+1%2C+2%5D%2C+%5B2%2C+1%5D%5D&debug=0)